# Convertion of integer value to char in C?

Tags: c, casting, integer, char

I need to convert integer value to char value in C. What is the proper way to do it ?

Regards...

Answer (score 6):

They're implicitly convertible...

```
int x = 65;
char c = x; // 'A'
putchar(x);
printf("%c", x);
char asciiz[] = { 65, 32, 66, 32, 67, 0 };
```

You can do it explicitly with e.g. `(char)65`, especially useful in C++ where overloading and templates make writing code that behaves different depending on the type common.

If you actually mean to get a (possibly multiple-)character representation of a number, then you can use printf("%d", x) to print it to standard output, or:

```
char buffer[16]; // biggest int is 4 billion so ~10 chars, round up for safety
sprintf(buffer, "%d", x);
// say x was 128, buffer now contains [0] = '1', [1] = '2', [2] = '8', [3] = NUL.
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be:

```
(char)my_int;
```

However, a simple `char` might not really be what you want. In C, there are ´signed char´, ´unsigned char´, and "plain" `char`. Unfortunately, it is implementation defined if a plain `char` is signed or unsigned. So, if you plan to use the down-casts integer in an environment where this matters, make sure to pick the correct char type.

Comment: Ok, back up, what are you trying to do? If, for example, you have an integer 65 and you convert it to a char it will still be 65, but it will print as `A` as the ascii code for `A` is 65. If you want to print `65` then you should print it as an integer, i.e. using `%d` when using `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get the char representation of the integer digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 0, you can simply do it like this:

```
char ToChar(int value)
{
   assert(value >= 0 && value <= 9);
   return '0' + value;
}
```

If you want to include hexadecimal digits into the mix, you can do this:

```
char ToChar(int value)
{
   assert(value >= 0 && value <= 15);
   return value < 10 ? '0' + value : 'a' + value - 10;
}
```

This will only work though, if the characters are ordered from '0' to '9' in your character set. I have never heard of a character set that doesn't have this property.

Comment: `'0'` to `'9'` are guaranteed to be contiguous in C. `'a'` to `'z'` usually are, but there is no guarantee.